# printing all images on the gallery of fancybox instead of one image?

Tags: html, css, fancybox

I am trying to print all the images on gallery, instead of the current  Pop-up image,

please check this code :

---

```
<div class="slick-slide slick-active" data-slick-index="0" aria-hidden="false" style="width: 128px;">
    <a style="text-align: center; display:block;" id="fancyLaunch102595156" href="#">
        <img src="/en/PublishingImages/156/156.jpg" alt="" style="border-color: #7990C2; width: 125px; height: 90px;  border:2px solid #7990C2;-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #333333; -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #333333; box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #333333; -moz-border-radius:10px; -webkit-border-radius:10px; border-radius:10px; " class="mCS_img_loaded">
        <font color="white"> some title </font>
    </a>
    <ul style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; overflow: hidden; display: none;" id="images102595156">
        <li>
            <a href="/en/PublishingImages/156/newsletter_156_1.jpg" rel="gallery">
                <img src="/en/PublishingImages/156/newsletter_156_1.jpg" alt="" style="width: 90px; height: 128px;" class="mCS_img_loaded">
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/en/PublishingImages/156/newsletter_156_2.jpg" rel="gallery">
                <img src="/en/PublishingImages/156/newsletter_156_2.jpg" alt="" style="width: 90px; height: 128px;" class="mCS_img_loaded">
            </a>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

---

how to show the two images for print.

thanks and best regards

Comment: Do you have a link to the actual page?

Comment: Yes , please check this one : 
http://www.kia.gov.kw/en/MEDIARESOURCES/newsletters/Pages/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

put the css from this file into this media query that isn't already in a media query, in fact put any css you are doing that isn't important to the print look into this kind of media query. I hope I picked the correct file, but you get the idea.

view-source:http://www.kia.gov.kw/_catalogs/masterpage/en-us/KIA/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css

```
@media screen
{
  /*! fancyBox v2.1.5 fancyapps.com | fancyapps.com/fancybox/#license */
.fancybox-wrap,
.fancybox-skin,
.fancybox-outer,
.fancybox-inner,
.fancybox-image,
.fancybox-wrap iframe,
.fancybox-wrap object,
.fancybox-nav,
.fancybox-nav span,
.fancybox-tmp
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.fancybox-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 8020;
}

.fancybox-skin {
    position: relative;
    background: #f9f9f9;
    color: #444;
    text-shadow: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
       -moz-border-radius: 4px;
            border-radius: 4px;
}

.fancybox-opened {
    z-index: 8030;
}

.fancybox-opened .fancybox-skin {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.fancybox-outer, .fancybox-inner {
    position: relative;
}

.fancybox-inner {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.fancybox-type-iframe .fancybox-inner {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.fancybox-error {
    color: #444;
    font: 14px/20px "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.fancybox-image, .fancybox-iframe {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.fancybox-image {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

#fancybox-loading, .fancybox-close, .fancybox-prev span, .fancybox-next span {
    background-image: url('fancybox_sprite.png');
}

#fancybox-loading {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -22px;
    margin-left: -22px;
    background-position: 0 -108px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 8060;
}

#fancybox-loading div {
    width: 44px;
    height: 44px;
    background: url('fancybox_loading.gif') center center no-repeat;
}

.fancybox-close {
    position: absolute;
    top: -18px;
    right: -18px;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 8040;
}

.fancybox-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: transparent url('blank.gif'); /* helps IE */
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    z-index: 8040;
}

.fancybox-prev {
    left: 0;
}

.fancybox-next {
    right: 0;
}

.fancybox-nav span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 36px;
    height: 34px;
    margin-top: -18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 8040;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.fancybox-prev span {
    left: 10px;
    background-position: 0 -36px;
}

.fancybox-next span {
    right: 10px;
    background-position: 0 -72px;
}

.fancybox-nav:hover span {
    visibility: visible;
}

.fancybox-tmp {
    position: absolute;
    top: -99999px;
    left: -99999px;
    visibility: hidden;
    max-width: 99999px;
    max-height: 99999px;
    overflow: visible !important;
}

/* Overlay helper */

.fancybox-lock {
    overflow: hidden !important;
    width: auto;
}

.fancybox-lock body {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}

.fancybox-lock-test {
    overflow-y: hidden !important;
}

.fancybox-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
    z-index: 8010;
    background: url('fancybox_overlay.png');
}

.fancybox-overlay-fixed {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.fancybox-lock .fancybox-overlay {
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

/* Title helper */

.fancybox-title {
    visibility: hidden;
    font: normal 13px/20px "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    text-shadow: none;
    z-index: 8050;
}

.fancybox-opened .fancybox-title {
    visibility: visible;
}

.fancybox-title-float-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 50%;
    margin-bottom: -35px;
    z-index: 8050;
    text-align: center;
}

.fancybox-title-float-wrap .child {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -100%;
    padding: 2px 20px;
    background: transparent; /* Fallback for web browsers that doesn't support RGBa */
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
       -moz-border-radius: 15px;
            border-radius: 15px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 2px #222;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 24px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.fancybox-title-outside-wrap {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: #fff;
}

.fancybox-title-inside-wrap {
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.fancybox-title-over-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #000;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}
fancybox-print {
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    bottom: 15px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: #333;
    font: normal 13px/20px "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.75);
    z-index: 8050;
    -moz-opacity: 0.75;
    opacity: 0.75;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha"(Opacity=75);

}

.fancybox-print:hover {
    -moz-opacity: 1;
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha"(Opacity=100);
 }



} /* end @media screen */

/*Retina graphics!*/
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
       only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
       only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5){

    #fancybox-loading, .fancybox-close, .fancybox-prev span, .fancybox-next span {
        background-image: url('fancybox_sprite@2x.png');
        background-size: 44px 152px; /*The size of the normal image, half the size of the hi-res image*/
    }



#fancybox-loading div {
        background-image: url('fancybox_loading@2x.gif');
        background-size: 24px 24px; /*The size of the normal image, half the size of the hi-res image*/
    }
}
```

Comment: dear I have separate CSS file for the print , but the issue is how to show all images inside the popup ,to print them all one time instead of printing the current image.